# Extract block of text using regex

Tags: php, regex

Using `PHP` I want to compare two text files, the first file is the main one that the other one should compare with it.
If a line of `first.txt` does not exist in `second.txt` or is different from it, the script should return the whole block of that line, for example:

**first.txt**

```
interface Vlan11
 description xxx
 ip address 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.255
 shutdown
!
vlan 34
!
vlan 17
 name sth
!
route-map sth
 match ip address exm
 set ip next-hop 1.2.3.4
!
```

**second.txt**

```
interface Vlan11
 description xxx
 ip address 20.20.20.20 255.255.255.255
 shutdown
!
vlan 34
!
route-map sth
 match ip address exm
 set ip next-hop 1.2.3.4
!
```

For the compare I extracted the `first.txt` lines using `file()` and search them in the `second.txt`, now the IP address is different in third line of `second.txt`, then we should return the block of this line (from `interface` to the bang(`!`)):

```
interface Vlan11
 description xxx
 ip address 20.20.20.20 255.255.255.255
 shutdown
!
```

or in the `second.txt` one of `vlan` blocks does not exists, so it should returns:

```
vlan 17
 name sth
!
```

It's easy to write a regex that extracts the block between the two bangs, but because I should go back to the start of block I don't know what the pattern should start with.

Also I have another idea that every block starts with a character, then some lines that start with a space and then a bang at the end, but the problem is about how to start the pattern.

Comment: Wouldn't `diff` do exactly what you want?

Comment: Are the blocks supposed to be in the same order in the two files?

Comment: which `diff`? @Jan

Comment: No, the order may be different in two files @CasimiretHippolyte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression to match blocks:

```
/.*?\R!\R*/s
```

The `\R` matches newlines, and the `s` modifier makes sure that `.` will also match newlines.

You could then use `preg_match_all` to get all blocks from a text, and use `array_diff` to make the comparison and extract the blocks that are different:

```
$text1 = file_get_contents("first.txt");
$text2 = file_get_contents("second.txt");

preg_match_all('/.*?\R!\R*/s', $text1, $blocks1);
preg_match_all('/.*?\R!\R*/s', $text2, $blocks2);

$result = array_diff($blocks1[0], $blocks2[0]);

print_r($result);
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/600417);

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to find the common and unique parts of the two files which are separated by '!'.

```
<?php

$first_txt = "interface Vlan11
 description xxx
 ip address 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.255
 shutdown
!
vlan 34
!
vlan 17
 name sth
!
route-map sth
 match ip address exm
 set ip next-hop 1.2.3.4
!
";


$second_txt = "interface Vlan11
 description xxx
 ip address 20.20.20.20 255.255.255.255
 shutdown
!
vlan 34
!
route-map sth
 match ip address exm
 set ip next-hop 1.2.3.4
!
";

$first_parts=explode('!',$first_txt);
$second_parts=explode('!',$second_txt);

print_r($first_parts);
print_r($second_parts);

foreach ( $first_parts as $part) 
{
    if ( in_array( $part, $second_parts ) )
    {
        echo "found in second_parts $part";
        echo "";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "not found in second_parts $part";
        echo "";
    }
}
foreach ( $second_parts as $part) 
{
    if ( in_array( $part, $first_parts ) )
    {
        echo "found in first_parts $part";
        echo "";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "not found in first_parts $part";
        echo "";
    }
}
```